# Where to put business logic layer when migrating from WCF to Web Api?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, architecture, webforms, asp.net-web-api

Our application is structured something like:

UI <--> Proxy <--> WCF Service <--> Business Logic <--> DAL(Entity Framework 4) <--> DB

Now we are planning to shift from WCF to Web Api(Rest API).The following is our new architectural design but I'm having trouble, where to put my "Business logic layer" ?.

UI <--> (BLL)?? <--> Web API(Rest API) <--> DAL(Entity Framework 5) <--> DB

Is it a good architectural design ?

Comment: Why not just swap out the WCF service for the Web API?

Comment: No I can't because WCF or ASMX-based web services are SOAP-based and there typically is an associated WSDL. WSDL allows tooling to be built around to generate proxy classes and all that but ASP.NET Web API is meant to build REST (or HTTP based) services and there is no meta data in the form of WSDL or anything similar and hence adding service reference through VS is not applicable for ASP.NET Web API

Comment: I disagree.  If I'm reading your diagram right, you currently have the UI using a proxy to a service that sits on top of your BLL.  I'm assuming that the service has a direct reference to the BLL.  If that's correct, I'd expect you could do a similar architecture with Web API - the Web API still has to connect to a service of some nature, albeit a REST service, right?  What doesn't make sense (to me, at least) is to move the service layer from between the UI and BLL to between the BLL and the DAL.

Comment: Agree with @Tim - WCF and Web API basically do the same thing (remote servicing), they should be a 1-for-1 replacement. Plus placing the BLL where you put it means it has a reference to web-related stuff, which is generally discouraged. Maybe you're confusing BLL with some kind of client-side model tailored for presentation (aka ViewModel) ?